# SQL Server rowversion and order

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using the `rowversion` property from several tables for change tracking. A periodic process queries many tables with a union all on `rowversion` converted to `BIGINT` datatype (as computed column). It then records the highest number read, and next time queries from that higher number.

I am observing that in high concurrency situations, where several threads are writing and one thread is querying for change, sometimes it ends up reading a higher `rowversion` value and then a lower number gets written.

The value with lower version never gets picked up, causing synchronization issues.

`rowversion` documentation on msdn states that

> The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number

Wondering if I can rely on it being incremental at the time of completing transaction or starting transactions ?

Using default transaction isolation of SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time of the increment is at the time of the change of the row, irrespective of when the transaction commits:

Example. (Note `@@dbts` is the current database rowversion value.)

```
select @@version
create table t (c int, rv rowversion)
go
begin transaction
print @@dbts
insert into t (c) values (1)
print @@dbts
insert into t (c) values (2)
print @@dbts
insert into t (c) values (3)
print @@dbts
commit
select * from t
```

Results, note that `@@dbts` increments with each insert and that the insert gets the higher incremented value. All within one transaction.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2254.0 (X64)
Jul 25 2014 18:52:51
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64>
(Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) 

0x00000000000007D0
0x00000000000007D1
0x00000000000007D2
0x00000000000007D3

C   RV
1   0x00000000000007D1
2   0x00000000000007D2
3   0x00000000000007D3
```

Comment: so reason why i am seeing newer values before older ( out of order) is because newer transactions are committed before older ? any thoughts on how to prevent this ?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent "out of order" `rowversion` numbers short disallowing concurrent writers. Synching is a hard problem and one I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Thank you both for this explanation and summary. Exactly the situation I'm in - at least I now know I'm not crazy. *_*